# Anything $\bigcap$ with a bounded set results in a bounded?

Tags: general-topology

I was reading a proof where it states let $A$ be a set, $I$ a bounded interval, then $A \cap I$ is bounded

In $\mathbb{R}$ it seems incontrovertible...does this statement hold irrefutably?

Comment: Absolutely. ${}{}$

Comment: Very mooving moniker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Bounded" makes sense in an arbitrary metric space: a set $A$ in a metric space $(X, d)$ is bounded if there is some $N\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for all $a, b$ in $A$, $d(a, b)<N$.

It's easy to show that if $A$ is bounded and $B\subseteq A$, then $B$ is also bounded (via the same $N$). Since $A\cap C$ is always a subset of $A$, this means the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: Oh right we don't have distance in general topological spaces, so there is no bizarro topology that messes this up

Comment: @TheSilenceoftheCows I think the right notion of boundedness in an arbitrary topological space is "is contained in a compact set" - but that's still preserved by shrinking the set. In general, any reasonable notion of boundedness should continue to hold if you make the set smaller.